# Check user browser support getBoundingClientRect() function or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, browser

I'm thinking to check about if visitor browser support getBoundingClientRect() then call the function below but if not support then don't call. Here is my not working code:

```js
    var benefitpub = document.getElementById('pubbox');
    var advbox2 = document.getElementById('advbox');

    window.onscroll = function () {
       if(benefitpub.getBoundingClientRect().top == true){ if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > benefitpub.getBoundingClientRect().top) {
            benefitpub.style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
         benefitpub.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        }
if(advbox2.getBoundingClientRect().top == true){
        if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > advbox2.getBoundingClientRect().top) {
            advbox2.style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
         advbox2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
        }
    }
```

```css
#advbox, #pubbox{
    margin-top: 500px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="advbox">
    Hello This is advbox
</div>

<div id="pubbox">
    Hello this is Pubbox
</div>
```

Any suggestion?? Or anyone understand how to do??

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to check to see if a function exists, is to use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof):

```
if (typeof benefitpub.getBoundingClientRect === 'function') {
    //Client supports getBoundingClientRect()
} else {
    //No support
}
```

If `benefitpub.getBoundingClientRect` is not defined, then the type would be `'undefined'`. Additionally, to check to see if this is supported without requiring any specific element, check the Element prototype:

```
if (typeof Element.prototype.getBoundingClientRect === 'function') {
    //Client supports getBoundingClientRect()
} else {
    //No support
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the function `getBoundingClientRect` exists on the element, and if not then the browser doesn't support it. Example:

```
var benefitpub = document.getElementById('pubbox');
if (benefitpub.getBoundingClientRect) {
  // run your code here
} else {
  // browser doesn't support it
}
```